# Same command for multiple views

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two identical views `View1.xaml` and `View2.xaml` and they both have a button `button1` and a textfield `textfield1`. The idea is that when you press the button, the corresponding textfield is filled with some information. Both views use the same method for filling in the textfield (the views are literally identical in that sense).

My question is: how to write generic code using OOP principles and not break the MVVM pattern? My current way of performing this with RelayCommand:

The same code for `ViewModel1` and `ViewModel2`:

```
public RelayCommand ButtonCommand { get; private set; }

#Constructor
ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteButtonCommand, CanExecuteButtonCommand);
#EndConstructor

private void ExecuteButtonCommand(object message)
{
    //Some method to fill the corresponding textfield
}

private bool CanExecuteButtonCommand(object message)
{
    return true;
}
```

Binding for the button in `View1.xaml` and `View2.xaml`:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=ButtonCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

This is bad, because I have to write the same code for both ViewModels. I was trying to make a class `ButtonCommand` which inherits from RelayCommand, but because not every view will have this functionality, I can't achieve it using this method.

Comment: Bind the Text property of the textboxes to the same ViewModel (you could create a base class for ViewModels that has this property) property.

Comment: Why can't you use the very same view model class for both views?

Comment: You can't use the same `ViewModel` for 2 different views because you break the pattern and it's 'readability'. If you have `MyView`, by convention it's VM is `MyViewModel` not `MyOtherViewModel`

Comment: @Babbillumpa I already have the `ViewModelBase` and the problem is that not every `ViewModel` has to have this functionality, thus I could only do another base class that would inherit from `ViewModelBase` and then be extended by these `ViewModels`

Comment: @karolyzz and what's stopping you to do this?

Comment: How many times are you duplicating this command? Duplicating this code once (Same command in 2 ViewModels) would not necessarily break SOLID principles, unless you know it's going to appear in a third or more VM's

Comment: It will appear in most of the VMs (it should be more than 4). The number is determined dynamically.

Comment: Which library are you using? Is this MVVM-Light's implementation of `RelayCommand`?

Comment: @AdamVincent I'm not using any frameworks, I wrote my own RelayCommand. It's just your typical RelayCommand implementing ICommand

Comment: @mm8 and how is it nonsense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having a "Base" view model and two derived view models, have your two view models both use the same code defined elsewhere (ideally, both calling the same interface, injected with dependency injection).

This is the Composition over Inheritance principle.

When you're writing your tests, test that both view models call the interface, and test that the implementation of that interface does what it is supposed to do once.

This way, not only can you avoid writing your code twice, you can also avoid testing it twice, and it also allows you to follow other principles like the single responsibility principle.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean having an interface for the command and its injection which contains the method? And then the viewmodels would simply call the interface?

Comment: The actual commands are properties of the view model, so that they can be bound to. The code executes for the command can just call a method on another class. Both view models can use that class without sharing a base class.

Comment: yeah, that's probably the way to go in this case

Comment: Referring back to this answer, it was probably the single most important answer in stack overflow I have ever read. Thank you, it has changed the way I look at software development and made me learn all kinds of new concepts. This was also definitely the best answer to this question, something that I was looking for at the time.

Answer (score 2):

This could be an way to go:

1 - Create a base viewmodel class:

```
public class YourBaseViewModel
{   
    public Object YourBaseProperty{get; set;}

    public RelayCommand ButtonCommand { get; private set; }

    private void ExecuteButtonCommand(object message)
    {
        //Some method to fill the corresponding textfield
    }

    private bool CanExecuteButtonCommand(object message)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

2 - Inherit from the base viewmodel:

```
public class ViewModel1:YourBaseViewModel
{    
  // .... 
}

public class ViewModel2:YourBaseViewModel
{    
  // .... 
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you have another base class you could do:

```
public class YourBaseViewModel:YourReallyBaseViewModel
{ 
    // ....
}

public class ViewModel1:YourBaseViewModel
{    
      // .... 
}

public class ViewModel2:YourBaseViewModel
{    
      // .... 
}
```

Comment: This will not work unfortunately, since if I then have `view3.xaml`, which has `button` and `textfield` associated with a new `command` and add the same `button` and `textfield` in already existing `view2.xaml`, then `view2.xaml` would have to extend two base classes and so on. In other words, it would not work if `view2` would have the functionality of `view1` and `view3`, but `view1` and `view3` would be completely different.

Comment: @karolyzz with "new command" you mean same Command but different Execute action?

Comment: Exmaple: `view1`'s button is responsible for generating a random number and `view3`'s button for generating a random string. Now if `view2` has two buttons, one for generating a string and one for number, this would no longer work as view2 would now have to have another class it extends with both of the functionalities.

Answer (score 2):

This is an XY problem.  You're asking for a way to solve Y (not duplicate the same `ButtonCommand` but in actuality), your problem is X (you *already* have duplication in your code)

> I have two identical views View1.xaml and View2.xaml

I'd like to add, that you've also stated you don't have *only* two identical views, there's more.

The best way to resolve this is to have a parent `ParentViewModel` that can construct the child ViewModels

So first, we'll need an interface for the child view model

#### IMyViewModel

```
public interface IMyViewModel
{
    void Load(); 
}
```

Next, the implementation

#### MyViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase, IMyViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel() 
    {
        ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteButtonCommand, CanExecuteButtonCommand);
    }
    
    public RelayCommand ButtonCommand { get; private set; }
    
    public void Load()
    {
        //Example load logic
        InvalidateCommands();
    }
    
    private void InvalidateCommands()
    {
        ButtonCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
        
    private void ExecuteButtonCommand(object message)
    {
        //Some method to fill the corresponding textfield
    }

    private bool CanExecuteButtonCommand(object message)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And lastly the `ParentViewModel` which has the responsibility of creating the view models. Please note, I did not tell it WHEN to create the ViewModels, I will leave that up to you.

#### Parent View Model

```
public class ParentViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{
    private Func<IMyViewModel> _myVmCreator;
    
    public ParentViewModel(Func<IMyViewModel> myVmCreator) 
    {
        _friendEditVmCreator = friendEditVmCreator;
    }
    
    public ObservableCollection<IMyViewModel> MyViewModels { get; private set; }
    
    private IMyViewModel CreateAndLoadMyViewModel()
    {
        var myVm = _myVmCreator();
        MyViewModels.Add(myVm);
        myVm.Load();
        return myVm;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to create any number of `MyViewModels`, or any other type of ViewModel as long as it implements `IMyViewModel`.

The above example is derived from this course : https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/wpf-mvvm-test-driven-development-viewmodels

I highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for such an extensive answer, it was really helpful.